# AppEngine: warning during python app update

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Everything worked perfect for the last few days, and now all of a sudden I get a warning spammed in the console when I update my app, but still the update is successful.

```
WARNING util.py:125 new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)
```

I looked at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\oauth2client\util.py at line 125, but couldn't make anything out of it.

The batch file I use to update my app is :

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] (echo Drag the app folder over the bat file.&&pause>nul&&exit)
C:
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine
C:\Python27\python appcfg.py update --oauth2 %1
echo Done.
pause>null
```

Comment: Which line is 125th? The 5th?

Comment: No, the warning is generated by 125th line in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\oauth2client\util.py. The second code in my post is just the batch file I created to update my app.

Comment: Well I can't find it in their [source code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/), maybe you're using an outdated version with a bug? Just post the line you see as the 125th in util.py

Comment: Version I use release: "1.8.3" timestamp: 1374030712 http://pastebin.com/kb3v8tDF - util.py

Comment: It is also in the source http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/oauth2client/util.py

Comment: Well all that code in the util file does, is it returns that error if more than one positional arguments were given. So we're back where we've started. The good news is, you don't have to worry about it (it's not a critical error) so you can just leave it be. Does the error appear when you are not using your batch file, and doing it manually instead?

Comment: Yes, the warning show up even if I do it manually. [Here](http://pastebin.com/C2x2sjPv) is a console output during update. The warning is shown at each step of the process.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing since 1.8.3 SDK update

Comment: Ditto. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: I'm still seeing this on 1.8.8 using google API client 1.2 in the app itself.

Answer (score 8):

I've confirmed the message is harmless so you can safely ignore it. We are working on a fix and should get one in to 1.8.4.

Comment: Wow, working on a fix (that deletes print to log) for a year and a half ? I'm a bit disappointed... :)

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda annoying. I'll ignore it for now, but when it logs the same error 50 times...

Comment: This seems more than harmless. Whenever this line appears, deployment takes significantly longer. It's as if there is a several minute delay whenever I see this message printed.

Comment: I keep getting 500 errors on 1.9.22 after this happens.

Comment: The 500 errors may be related to this outage, and they may trigger this bug, too.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/30883905/584846

Answer (score 4):

It seems the warnings on `appcfg.py` and only if `--oauth2` option is used. I'm not sure, but not on your apps. Without `--oauth2` option, there are no warning.

Comment: Obviously, since util.py is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\oauth2client . Perhaps the token file needs to be reseted. Where is located that token file?

Comment: Wow! The token is located in Windows UserProfile folder, named .appcfg_oauth2_tokens. Edit: I've rested the token .. warning still shows up.

Comment: Fixed by [GAE 1.8.4](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.8.4_-_September_9,_2013).

Answer (score 2):

While the warnings are ugly they are safe to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Editing this answer with updated information: The 1.9.26 SDK includes [this patch](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/pull/196) that I made to the oauth2client library. So the problem should now be fixed.

Previous answer below.

A fix to a similar problem was indeed included in the SDK in 2013, but it looks as if there are some circumstances in which it can still arise. We haven't been able to reproduce the problem, so could I ask someone who is seeing it to do the following? In the SDK install directory, edit
google_appengine/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/util.py and find the line that looks like this:

```
      if len(args) > max_positional_args:
```

In the current version it is line 125. After that line, indented two spaces further, add this:

```
        import traceback; traceback.print_stack()
```

If someone can copy one of the tracebacks that produces here, we should be able to identify and fix the problem.

Comment: I was looking for the place to add this line but only found util.py in oauth2client folder in my sources. No where in SDK, it has no directory oauth2client. where is this located?