# Cannot access Google App Engine dashboard and upload Python app

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This morning I made some changes to my Python web app, and then I uploaded my App using the tool provided by Google. But it stopped at  "Compilation starting", and it showed error 500 after couple minutes. In the same time, I cannot access the dashboard of the app.

I have never faced this situation.
Did anyone experience the same situation? Or what might cause this situation?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/GpSzIrGBvuE

Comment: Thanks to your information! My problem is solved.